# How many times/fold a number is greater or smaller in data frame-R

Tags: r

I need to compute how many times or folds the gene-gene correlation is changed (either increased or decreased) in State 2 with respect to State 1 (Control).

I have a data frame in the following form, where State 1 and State 2 are the correlation values (among genes) across the two states.

```
Gene1      Gene2   State 1         State 2
TGFBR2     MAP2K1 -9.551574e-02  0.084986632
TGFBR2     TGFB1  -4.062619e-02  0.363522413
TGFBR2     STAT1  -2.412670e-02  0.025109928
```

I am computing the fold change as

```
df[,4]/df[,3]
```

as suggested in https://www.biostars.org/p/209790/

However, I am not sure that the result obtained is correct. Any ideas will be acknowledged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will almost never see fold changes of correlation coefficients computed in RNA seq experiments for a number of reasons. For example the correlation values you present contain negatives; so a change of -0.5 to 0.5 should be considered a very large change in the context of RNA seq but will give you a fold change value of -1. Whereas your second row gives a value of -9.

One option would be to remove the negative values by computing r squared values. Though this also is not optimal.

Another option would be to compute the z score of the correlation coefficient within each group, then to compare the z score of the correlation between groups. This is better because it gives a unit relative to your dataset and allows for statistical testing of the differences.

Probably the best option is to utilize statistical approaches specifically for comparing correlation coefficients in seq data implemented in R packages. Two examples are DGCA which is easy to implement but I'm not sure if still maintained:
https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12918-016-0349-1

Another is EBcoexpress. This vignette gives a nice overview of the statistics underlying the comparisons: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBcoexpress/inst/doc/EBcoexpressVignette.pdf

Hope that is helpful

Comment: Thank you mikeHoncho for the answer. It really helped.